# How to apply a background for children (they already have a background set) on the foreground of the others?

Tags: html, css

Hello I have an html like this:

```html
<html>
<div class="container">
    <span class="child1">
      child1
    </span>
    <span class="child2">
      child2
    </span>
</div>
</html>
```

Image of what i want:
[image]

I would like to see the backgroundColor of `container` at the foreground of others childs backgroundColor.
If the backgroundColor of the container have half opacity then the container bg color and child bg color should merge.

Here a (not) woking example:
https://codepen.io/Pricex3/pen/qBRXJdY

The problem here is the backgroundColor of the container is not applied on hover on the foreground of the others divs.

What is the problem ?

Comment: So create a another selector to override the bg color of the child.

Comment: SCSS does not work in a Snippet. What you do have works though https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/mdRMGpj Perhaps you have not explained the issue properly?

Comment: I edited my issue

Comment: @Theo Cerutti - One clarification - Do you want to apply a background-color to the whole container (on hover) and then want your child divs also to have the same background - color (on hover of container) ? If so, I have updated my answer to reflect the same.

Comment: I will post a image of what i want, it will be easier for us

Comment: I posted the image of what i want :)

Comment: @TheoCerutti Updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed a few things and I think you can achieve what you want like so (using `nth-of-type` or `nth-child` and `mix-blend-mode`) :-

```css
.container:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

.child {
  mix-blend-mode: color-burn;
}

.child:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

.child:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="container">
  <span class="child">
      child1
    </span>
  <span class="child">
      child2
    </span>
</div>

</html>
```

You can also try `mix-blend-mode` with `saturation` and `overlay` which gives a variation of your required result.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: I also added a isolation: isolate; to container to don't blend with background

Answer (score 1):

A different idea where you apply another layer using background-image:

```css
.container:hover>.child {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4) 0 0);
}

.child:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: green;
}

.child:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  padding:20px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="child">
      child1
    </span>
  <span class="child">
      child2
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

In normal css you would do:

```css
.child1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.container:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="container">
    <span class="child1">
      child1
    </span>
    <span class="child2">
      child2
    </span>
</div>
</html>
```

When you hover over the .container or the elements within it the .container:hover{} css will apply to it.

Answer (score -2):

The hover is still applying but only for himself is not affecting their children

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.1rem;
}
.container:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
/* override CSS with important key*/
 .container span:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
 <html>
    <div class="container">
        <span class="child1">
          child1
        </span>
        <span class="child2">
          child2
        </span>
    </div>
    </html>
```